# How do you extend VS Code's built-in text editor?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'd like to create a VS Code extension which extends VS Code's built-in text editor.

Basically, I want to be able to add something similar to badges like you'd see in Markdown right in the built-in text editor. That is, interactive buttons inline with the rest of the text which abstract some underlying actual text or data. So if I type a certain token, it will be rendered as a badge (though the text document will actually contain only text). And contrariwise, perhaps if I interact with the badge (e.g. hover or click event) it could alter the text it represents.

I know about the [custom editor API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-editors), but don't want to write a whole editor from scratch. There are a lot of features in the built-in text editor that I would not like to write myself. I just want to add functionality to the existing text editor, especially to the webview. While I want my extension to communiate with language servers, I also can't just use the [language server API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide) because I want control over the visual representation in the text editor. I haven't come across official documentation for this kind of thing. Can this be done and where would I get started?

Comment: It depends on what kind of functionality you want to add. Could you tell us what you want to do?

Comment: @md2perpe Sure, I edited my question with more detail. Let me know if that's sufficient information or not.

Comment: Do you need to insert images?

Comment: @md2perpe Hmm, "need" might be a strong word. Not necessarily. I suppose it would be nice if I could, though.

Comment: I think that you can come quite far with [text editor decorations](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DecorationRenderOptions).

Comment: @md2perpe Thank you, I'll start there. But I suspect I will need a bit more control than I can get from text decorations. For example, I was hoping to show my own popup box much like the built-in code auto-completion box when I interact with my "badges." And maybe I actually will want to insert SVG icons or do other things beyond text styling. Am I out of luck?

Comment: Perhaps you can [register an InlineCompletionItemProvider](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#languages.registerInlineCompletionItemProvider) and get at least some of the "popup box" functionality that you want. But you might not get all what you want just using the API on a normal editor.